# javascript to php value not sending/adding

Tags: php, javascript, echo

I must be tired or something because i am unable to get this line of code to work:

```
var all = color.val('all');
$('#cssColor" + <?php echo $page ?> + "', parent.document).attr("background-color", all.hex);
```

I even have a textbox with the **page** value as well and i try:

```
var all = color.val('all');
$('#cssColor" + $('#txtPageValue').val() + "', parent.document).attr("background-color", all.hex);
```

I can not seem to send the page value!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `var all = color.val('all');` ??

Comment: @hsalama: Its a hex color value. It comes formatted like **#54ff65** etc etc

Comment: I am sorry, I am not too familiar with php, so is that line a php code? if so, when you console it out, does it contain the value you expect?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code snippet is riddled with parse errors...

Comment: Is this giving you a php error? Because it should.

Comment: ... for example `$('#cssColor" +`... why do you open with single quotes and finish with double quotes?

Comment: yeah, you have wrong pair of quotes in your code.

Comment: Try to clean the code a bit to avoid tangled quotes

    var txtPageValue = $('#txtPageValue').val();
    $("#cssColor" + txtPageValue + "", parent.document).attr("background-color", all.hex);

Comment: If you show us the HTML this is trying to alter we're going to be way better off. The `var all...` line really seems off.

Comment: Yes, we need to see the HTML. I wrote an answer, only to realize then that I'm not sure how you're assigning the variable all and how it has a hex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this one:

```
$('#cssColor" + <?php echo $page ?> + "',
```

to:

```
$('#cssColor<?php echo $page ?>',
```

And also, for the second one:

```
$('#cssColor" + $('#txtPageValue').val() + "',
```

to:

```
$('#cssColor' + $('#txtPageValue').val(),
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are assigning the all variable, but assuming it is getting assigned correctly, you could rewrite your code something like this to get the value to appear in the right place in your javascript:

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        //code somewhere in here should define the color object
        var all = color.val('all')
        $('#cssColor" . $page . "', parent.document).attr('background-color', all.hex);
    </script>"; ?>
```

This writes the javascript to the document, without breaking the echo function in the middle.

Or, you could do this:

```
var all = color.val('all');
$('#cssColor'+<?php echo $page; ?>, parent.document).attr('background-color', all.hex);
```